# What is "pishantosh"?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

I found the word in [Heinlein's "Friday"](http://m.litfile.net/read/178066/105903-107047?page=35):

> I apologized, saying that there was no excuse for me to be sleepy since it was still early evening by the zone where I had started the day.
>
> Janet said **pishantosh**, that being sleepy had nothing to do with clocks and time zones -- gentlemen, we are going to bed. She led me away.

I think, I can grasp the meaning from the above context, but I'm surprised, search-engines return nothing useful for it. What does the word actually mean and where is it coming from?

Comment: Bah and humbug! [Pish](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pish) and [tosh!](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tosh)

Comment: The close votes asking for more research ... there's nothing coming back on a google search. I don't know where else someone could look for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a variation of **pish and tosh, pish tosh** or **pish-tush**, the latter being the name of a character in Gilbert and Sullivan;s *The Mikado*.

[Slangwords Dictionary](http://slangwordsdictionary.com/pish-tosh) (hardly the OED, but **pishandtosh!** we're talking about a quaint colloquialism here) offers the following:

> **Pish Tosh**
>   Rubbish, bunk, a ridiculous proposition.
>   Popularized in the quippy expression; "Pish Tosh and a bottle of Pinosh on a hot summer's day in Koshkonong!"
>   Rubbish, Bunk, A perposterous proposition.
>   Made popular by the quippy expression; "Pish Tosh and a bottle of Pinosh on a hot summer's day in Koshkonong!"
>   The sound a t*rd makes when it hits the water.
>   Dude, I was in the bathroom, and it was all like "Pish tosh" and stuff! It was intense!

*Heinlein seems to have enjoyed using euphemisms for more serious maledictions, the stranger and more obscure the better.*